# How to replace a line from another file MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I have cell Array like this:

```
M =
 [002]  [A] [0] [0]   [0]     [381]
 [002]  [B] [0] [0]   [0]     [166]
 [002]  [C] [0] [0]   [0]     [136]
 [002]  [D] [0] [0]   [0]     [880]
 [003]  [E] [0] [0]   [0]     [839]
 [003]  [F] [0] [0]   [0]     [156]
 [003]  [G] [0] [0]   [0]     [789]
 [003]  [H] [0] [0]   [0]     [676]
 [003]  [I] [0] [0]   [0]     [778]
 [004]  [J] [0] [0]   [0]     [787]
```

and I have an input file which contain:

```
[X] [4] [3]  [E]      [839]
[Y] [7] [4]  [F]      [156]
[Z] [8] [1]  [I]      [778]
```

I want the third column from the second file `([E], [F], and [I])` to be the indices to find the value in M and then replace the row in M (but didnt change the first column of M), so i get new matrix like this:

```
N =
 [002]  [A] [0] [0]   [0]     [381]
 [002]  [B] [0] [0]   [0]     [166]
 [002]  [C] [0] [0]   [0]     [136]
 [002]  [D] [0] [0]   [0]     [880]
 [003]  [X] [4] [3]   [E]     [839]
 [003]  [Y] [7] [4]   [F]     [156]
 [003]  [G] [0] [0]   [0]     [789]
 [003]  [H] [0] [0]   [0]     [676]
 [003]  [Z] [8] [1]   [I]     [778]
 [004]  [J] [0] [0]   [0]     [787]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: [E], [F] and [I] are in 4th column; not 3rd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`ismember`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html).

```
N = M;                                     %Making a copy of M
N(ismember(M(:,2),inp(:,4)),2:end) = inp;  %Replacing with desired terms from input
```

<sup>Read: [Access Data in Cell Array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much!!